# Does normalized gradient flow preserve level sets?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, gradient-flows

Suppose that $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is a $C^1$ function such that $\nabla f(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$. Consider the initial value problem 
$$
\begin{cases} \dot{u}=-\frac{\nabla f(u)}{|\nabla f(u)|}, \\ u(0)=x,\end{cases}$$
and let $\Phi(t, x):=u(t).$

> **Question**. Let $a\in\mathbb R$. Is it true that $f$ is constant on $\Phi(t, \{ f=a\})$? Assume that $t$ is sufficiently small.

Here, of course, $\Phi(t, \{f=a\})$ denotes the set $\{\Phi(t, x)\ :\ f(x)=a\}$.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1558684/8157) might contain the answer in a differential geometric language. However, it is interesting to see an elementary answer.

Comment: This seems totally unlikely unless $\nabla f$ has constant length to start with. Without that, a level set will not flow to another level set under this flow.

Comment: You are essentially asking if any two level sets are "parallel", i.e. equally distant everywhere, which is false. As an explicit counterexample, consider the function $\max(x,2y)$, sufficiently smoothed near $x=2y$ if you like. Then $(10,0)$ and $(0,5)$ lie on the same level set but $\phi(1,(10,0))=(9,0)$ and $\phi(1,(0,4))$ do not.

Comment: Another way to see this: $\dot f=-\|\nabla f\|\ne{\rm const}$ under this flow. However, the "anti-normalized" gradient flow $\dot u=-\nabla f/\|\nabla f\|^2$ does preserve level sets (for sufficiently small times).

Comment: Thank you both for the useful information. It seems that I was missing a square in the denominator. @Rahul: if you put that in the form of an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Could any of you clarify whether $f$ is also changing with $t$ here?

Comment: Relatedly, if $f$ is indeed changing over time, would the "anti-normalized gradient flow" still preserve level sets?

Comment: @Confusian: I tried to give it a thought but then I completely forgot. I think this deserves a new question of its own.